# Using __new__ to override __init__ in subclass

Tags: python, object, methods, instance, object-initializers

I'm interested in using the `__new__` functionality to inject code into the `__init__` function of subclasses. My understanding from the documentation is that python will call `__init__` on the instance returned by `__new__`. However, my efforts to change the value of `__init__` in the instance before returning it from `__new__` don't seem to work.

```python
class Parent(object):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new_object = super(Parent, cls).__new__(cls)
        user_init = new_object.__init__
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("New __init__ called")
            user_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.extra()
        print("Replacing __init__")
        setattr(new_object, '__init__', __init__)
        return new_object

    def extra(self):
        print("Extra called")

class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        print("Original __init__ called")
        super(Child, self).__init__()

c = Child()
```

The above code prints:

```
Replacing __init__
Original __init__ called
```

but I would expect it to print

```
Replacing __init__
New __init__ called
Original __init__ called
Extra called
```

Why not?

I feel like Python is calling the original value of `__init__`, regardless of what I set it to in `__new__`. Running introspection on `c.__init__` shows that the new version is in place, but it hasn't been called as part of the object creation.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the new object is expected to be empty before the `__init__` is called. So probably python, as optimization, does not bother to query the object and goes to fetch `__init__` straight from the class.

Therefore you'll have to modify `__init__` of the subclasses themselves. Fortunately Python has a tool for that, metaclasses.

In Python 2, you set metaclass by setting special member:

```
class Parent(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta
    ...
```

See [Python2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation)

In Python 3, you set metaclass via keyword attribute in the parent list, so

```
class Parent(metaclass=Meta):
    ...
```

See [Python3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation)

The metaclass is a base class for the class instance. It has to be derived from `type` and in it's `__new__` it can modify the class being created (I believe the `__init__` should be called too, but the examples override `__new__`, so I'll go with it). The `__new__` will be similar to what you have:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
        new_cls = super(Meta, mcs).__new__(mcs, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
        user_init = new_cls.__init__
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("New __init__ called")
            user_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self.extra()
        print("Replacing __init__")
        setattr(new_cls, '__init__', __init__)
        return new_cls
```

(using the Python 3 example, but the signature in Python 2 seems to be the same except there are no `**kwargs`, but adding them shouldn't hurt; I didn't test it).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the answer is that `__init__` is a special function, internally it is defined as a class method, and as a result cannot be replaced by reassigning it in an instance of the object.

In Python, all objects are represented by the `PyObject` in C, which has a pointer to a `PyTypeObject`. This contains a member called `tp_init` that I believe contains a pointer to the `__init__` function.

The other solution works, because we are modifying the class, not an instance of the object.

Comment: `PyTypeObject` represents `type` object, not all objects, no?

Comment: Argh. Was looking for ``PyObject`` in the source code via github and found ``PyTypeObject`` instead. A ``PyObject`` has a ``ob_type`` method that does point to a ``PyTypeObject`` so I think my reasoning still could stands. It really depends on how the ``__init__`` method is called.

Comment: Rewrote my answer to try and simplify.